# MutationObserver is not getting any new element created

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

```
    (function getCloseBox (){
    let target = document.body;
    let MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
    let mutation = new MutationObserver((mutations)=>{
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
        if(document.getElementById("pb_layout")){
            console.log("it is found");
        }else{
            console.log("it is not found");
        }
    });
    let config = { attributes: true, childList: true,subtree: true ,characterData: true}
    mutation.observe(target, config);
})();
```

here in the if statement I am checking for the element which will load after an ajax call in a website but in that website, this element is loaded but the mutation observer not found the change in the body. Executing else statement only and This functionality is for an extension so I don't have a access to ajax response.
Please help

Comment: 1. Is this code inside the *content script*? 2. It's possible to intercept ajax response by spoofing XMLHttpRequest prototype inside [code inserted in a `<script>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: yeah it is inside the content script ? why it is not getting the element and
setinterval way also not working

Comment: The code seems fine. Make sure there's no a second element with the same id - duplicates prevent getElementById from working.

Comment: at what point in time do you register your callback? and have you made sure the body node does not get swapped in the meantime?